# Migrating to Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, firebase-authentication

Currently, I am using node as backend and looking forward to shift my project to django-rest-framework. In node I used firebase-auth and MySQL and have a table called `FIREBASE_USERS` with `email` and `firebase_uid` fields. I was thinking of building my own custom auth for drf but can't figure out on using my `FIREBASE_USERS` table instead of django `Users` model. I read that django provides settings. `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to set your own custom model but the documentation uses `AbstractUser` class to create that and I don't want to mess with my tables since the tables are used in other projects too. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom user model needs to contain the properties as described in (1). `AbstractBaseUser` is a shortcut to achieve this. Override the `Meta.db_table` to match you table name. If this is somehow not sufficient, consider creating your own authentication backend as described in (2) and create a django user with a foreign key to your firebase user. But in order to let django function properly your user model needs to have the methods as described in (1).

Maybe (3) solves your problem?

(1) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser

(2) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend

(3) https://github.com/fcornelius/django-firebase-auth

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply. I ended up creating my own custom authentication class using the BaseAuthentication class provided by DRF. However it is giving the following error 'FirebaseUser' (this is the name of my custom user model) object has no attribute 'is_authenticated', I checked the django docs and it says is_authenticated is a field on user object which is always True for a user but i don't have that field in my custom model. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Made it work by overwriting BasePermission class from DRF, thanks for your help.